# How to edit css margin-top for a text in mobile version

Tags: html, css

I want to edit the margin-top of a text in the mobile device. I have come this far but I know there is something crazy in the code:

```
.Foljoss {
padding-left: 18px;
background: #fff;
}

@media screen and 
  (max-width: 768px; margin-top:17px)
```

It is the last part in which I dont get it. How can I adjust the top margin for the `<div class="Foljoss">` on the mobile version? Notice that the `@media screen`-part is not correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to wrap the css inside a selector inside the media query.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .Foljoss {
     margin-top: 17px;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.show-on-mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .show-on-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .hide-on-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="show-on-mobile">Only visible when width is <= 568px</div>
<div class="hide-on-mobile">Disappears when screen width > 568px</div>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you. I just have asmal question, the `max-width:768px`-part, what does it really do? I have never really had a grip on that since it varies ?

Comment: It's some kind of a trigger to run the code inside the mediaquery, in this case it applies the css from the query when the window width is less than 768px

Comment: I added a runnable example to the post :) You can read more about media queries here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Surely it should be max-width: 767px for mobile? - 768px includes tablets.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* 767 is max for mobile */    
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .Foljoss {
         margin-top: 17px;
      }
    }
```

Comment: adding an explanation can be helpful

Comment: I thought I had added an explanation by way of the comment above the CSS, but here's some more. In Bootstrap phones are devices less than 768px  See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid